# Why using this method to return a function or value?

Tags: javascript, return

I'm just wondering why should I use this method to return a function :

```
clusters.prototype.get_local_storage_data = function(data_key) {
    return +(this.localStorage.getItem(data_key) || 1);
};
```

What does the `+()` do there and why using that ? Is there a better way of returning the function or 1 if what the function gets is null ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `+` before a value forces that value to become a number. In the case above, the data key will be converted to a number (if it's found), or the number 1 will be returned. Either way, the result will be converted to a number.

```
+null;   // 0
+"3.14"; // 3.14
+1;      // 1
```

It's just ensuring that no matter what the output is, you will be returning a `number`.

Comment: I see now, it comes in handy in my case, because the returned value is in fact a number, and will always be a number, at least that is what I expect it to be.

Comment: @Roland: `getItem` returns a string: http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#storage-0

Comment: I know that, but what I store is a number, so after I get it, using `JSON.parse()` it is the same thing I stored. It might as well be an object or an array, because I'm using `JSON.stringfy()`. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: @Roland If you're using `JSON.parse()` on the returned string, you will also end up with a number.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` is there to cast the result to a number -

```
typeof +"123" // "number"
```

The way it's implemented looks just fine, and doesn't need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` is just making sure the return value is a number or else `1` would be `true` and not the number one. It's a shortcut for:

```
Number( expression )
```